# How can I convert values from meters to km in a list (from html_nodes) with r?

Tags: r, if-statement, converters

I have the following list from

```
distance_to_center <- html_nodes(HouseRentingPage, xpath = '//*[@class="distance"]')
distance_to_center <- html_text(distance_to_center)
```

(ps: it is a partial list - the original has more than 3 thousand observations)

```
 distance_to_center

[1]"822 m" "500 m" "12.8 km" "435 m" NA "1 km" "985 m" "3.5 km" "4.9 km" "623 m"
```

How can I convert the values that are in meters to km? I tried to use if-statement but it is not working.

Comment: How about dividing by 1000? *"I tried to use if-statement..."*. Share this code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#Identifying the values in meter
chk <-  grep(" m", distance_to_center)

#Converting m into km
distance_to_center[chk] <- paste(as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", 
                                                 distance_to_center[chk]))/1000, 
                                 "km")  
distance_to_center

[1] "0.822 km" "0.5 km"   "12.8 km"  "0.435 km" NA         "1 km"     "0.985 km" "3.5 km"   "4.9 km"   "0.623 km"
```